# Possible to search by author name with default WordPress search function?

Tags: functions, search, author

I realize improving WordPress's search function is a huge can of worms, but the ONLY additional thing I need it to do is to show results when I search for an author's name.

For example, if we have an author named Katie Johnson, and I search for Katie, I get results where her name is listed in the CONTENT, but not results that she POSTED.

This seems like a simple problem, and yet I haven't yet found a solution to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can try adding your condition directly in the query string, using something like this

```
function wpse_29570_where_filter($where){
        global $wpdb;
        if( is_search() ) {
            $search= get_query_var('s');
            $query=$wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_id  FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE ( meta_key='first_name' AND meta_value LIKE '%%%s%%' ) or ( meta_key='last_name' AND meta_value LIKE '%%%s%%' )", $search ,$search);
            $authorID= $wpdb->get_var( $query );

            if($authorID){
                $where = "  AND  ( wp_posts.post_author = {$authorID} ) ";
            }

         }
         return $where;
    }

    add_filter('posts_where','wpse_29570_where_filter');
```

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do here, but it unfortunately, is not working for me. This actually unsets the query string and then sets author_name to nothing. I believe the results are EVERYTHING that's been posted.

Comment: Updated my answer to something that could work better

Comment: I updated to this code, and it doesn't seem to be returning all the results from the user. While it does return SOME results, I'm not sure which ones its picking and which ones are being left out, or WHY. Basically, the results for a search of a user's name and the archive for that user are drastically different.

Comment: Well this will return for the search term and results for the user first or lastnmae close to the string you are searching for,
if you want results ONLY from the author then you will change
`$where = "  {$where}   OR  ( wp_posts.post_author = {$authorID} ) ";`

with

`$where = " AND wp_posts.post_author = {$authorID} ";`

Or if you want to search other users field you may need to edit the first edit field

Comment: the first situation you described is what I want it to do, but unfortunately not what is happening. A search result for "Stephanie" (without quotes) returns only ONE result where the query is the author (but 3 other normal results). when I navigate to that users archive, I see all SEVEN posts by them.

Comment: I edited to match you request (With the where with only AND) works for me, but note that im checking author first name and last name only, maybe you want to search by nice name, display name or username?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1452/discussion-between-hansy-schmitt-and-zack)

Comment: This is pretty slick. Worked great! Need to remove the `echo $where;` statement though. That isn't ideal...

Comment: @Jake you are right :) , I guess at that time I forgot to remove that line when testing.
Updated the answer

Comment: The `$where =` should probably be `$where .=`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get either of those answers to work for me, but I found this:
https://danielbachhuber.com/2012/02/07/include-posts-by-matching-authors-in-your-search-results/

Worked without any edits. Here's the code incase the link is ever out of date:

```
    /**
 * Include posts from authors in the search results where
 * either their display name or user login matches the query string
 *
 * @author danielbachhuber
 */
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'db_filter_authors_search' );
function db_filter_authors_search( $posts_search ) {

    // Don't modify the query at all if we're not on the search template
    // or if the LIKE is empty
    if ( !is_search() || empty( $posts_search ) )
        return $posts_search;

    global $wpdb;
    // Get all of the users of the blog and see if the search query matches either
    // the display name or the user login
    add_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'db_filter_user_query' );
    $search = sanitize_text_field( get_query_var( 's' ) );
    $args = array(
        'count_total' => false,
        'search' => sprintf( '*%s*', $search ),
        'search_fields' => array(
            'display_name',
            'user_login',
        ),
        'fields' => 'ID',
    );
    $matching_users = get_users( $args );
    remove_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'db_filter_user_query' );
    // Don't modify the query if there aren't any matching users
    if ( empty( $matching_users ) )
        return $posts_search;
    // Take a slightly different approach than core where we want all of the posts from these authors
    $posts_search = str_replace( ')))', ")) OR ( {$wpdb->posts}.post_author IN (" . implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $matching_users ) ) . ")))", $posts_search );
    return $posts_search;
}
/**
 * Modify get_users() to search display_name instead of user_nicename
 */
function db_filter_user_query( &$user_query ) {

    if ( is_object( $user_query ) )
        $user_query->query_where = str_replace( "user_nicename LIKE", "display_name LIKE", $user_query->query_where );
    return $user_query;
}
```

Comment: Found a bit different informations about [`get_users`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/), e.g.: [`search`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/#search-parameters) parameter can be a simple string and the recommended filter to modify the columns is [`user_search_columns`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_search_columns/). Great answer otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Improving on @hacksy's answer, I have used the same block of code but changing it to successfully search company name using the [WP Job Manager plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/).

```
function add_author_to_search($where) {
    global $wpdb;
    if( is_search() ) { // Check if a search is made
        $search = get_query_var('s');
        $like = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $search ) . '%';
        $query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE ( meta_key='first_name' AND lower(meta_value) LIKE '%%%s%%' ) OR ( meta_key='last_name' AND lower(meta_value) LIKE '%%%s%%' ) OR ( meta_key='_company_name' AND lower(meta_value) LIKE '%%%s%%' )", $search, $search, $search);
        $authorID = $wpdb->get_var( $query );

        if ($authorID) { // If a user_id matches a user
            $where .= " OR " .$wpdb->posts. ".post_author = {$authorID} AND " .$wpdb->posts. ".post_name LIKE '" .$like. "'"; // Add to query of function: $GLOBALS[$WP_QUERY_VAR]->request
        }
     }
     return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where','add_author_to_search');
```

What it does is search the `meta_key` column of the `first_name`, `last_name`, and `_company_name` values then check for a value under the `meta_value` to see if it matches the search query. If a user_id is found, the SQL search query is appended to search for the post_author ID and if the slug of the company is found under the `post_name` column.

Comment: Good call on the esc_like, but shouldn't you be using that in $query too?