# Display posts from an author using search parameters (not author template/query_posts)

Tags: search, author, terms, parameter

Is there a way to retrieve a list of all the posts by an author using search (example: ?s&author=xxx)? I can't use query_posts or author template (don't ask why, take it as a condition).
And it should be a public query (the filter in admin panel isn't good).

If isn't available by default as a search parameter, do you know how to add it smoothly through functions.php (without flooding WP with db queries or requests that slow it down).

Comment: Possible duplicate. [Possible to search by author name with default WordPress search function?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29561/possible-to-search-by-author-name-with-default-wordpress-search-function)

Comment: I found out a solution better than the one in the other topic.

Comment: Something like /?s=%20&author_name=username works, but if there's something that sets search term to none would be better (to not display "search results for ''). :)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I was looking for:

```
/?s=+&author_name=username
```

Comment: For me this didn't work but `/?s=&author=40` did work where `40` is the user ID.