# How to add the author search in the default wordpress search?

Tags: search, author

I would like to include the author search in the default WordPress search. Is there any way of doing this? right know it retrieves all the posts with the permalinks and author names. same way i need the authors search. is it possible?

Comment: What author search?

Comment: i need to search the users and retrieve their posts like the default search.suppose i am searching naveen, so i want to retrieve all posts from naveen.

Comment: Do you want to just search authors, or include authors into the default post search?

Comment: include authors in to the default search.

Comment: Search the site please: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=include+authors+in+search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plugin called "WP Extended Search" looks like it would do the trick.: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-extended-search/

There's also this answer that may work for you: [Possible to search by author name with default WordPress search function?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29561/possible-to-search-by-author-name-with-default-wordpress-search-function)